Prime factor $p$ of $n!+1$ such that $n$ does not divide $p-1$
I'm currently doing this problem:

Prove that there are infinitely many prime $p$ such that there exists a number $n$ satisfying $n!+1$ is divisible by $p$ and $n$ does not divide $p-1$.

For example, $(p,n)=(61,8)$ is a pair we're looking for since $61|(8!+1)$ and $8\nmid 60$. We have to prove there are infinitely many such pairs.
Since I only need to prove there are infinitely many of them, I've tried to look at some special form of $n$. My idea is for $n=2^k$, and $p$ is a prime factor of $n!+1=(2^k)!+1$, I can somehow calculate $v_2(p-1)$. If $v_2(p-1)<k$ for $k$ large enough, we are done! So my questions are:

Is there any way to calculate $v_2(p-1)$ (or find its upper-bound) for some prime factor $p$ of $(2^k)!+1$?
Is there another approach for the original problem?


Although it might be inconvenient, you should consider the formula listed here which is derived from Legendre's formula for $\nu_p(n!)$. As for an alternate approach, perhaps Wilson's Theorem might help
